# Formula to search for an integer value in a range (2d grid)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a grid of cells/range/table containing integer values, e.g., A1 to E10.

I would like a formula to search for the first occurrence of the value X and return its location within the A1:E10 range.

I can see how to search for a value in a single column/row, but not in a range/grid/table.

eg look for value 99 which could be in any column A to E and any row 1 to 10

Sample grid of numbers (5 rows), not sorted, some repeating numbers.

......A.. .B.. ..C.. .D.. ..E
1.. 11.. 21.. 51.. 77.. 11
2.. 12..  11..  55..  23..  89
3.. 15..  33..  01..  55.. 10
4.. 19..  15..  02..  05.. 01
5.. 21..  42..  07..  12..  23

(Grid of integers, dots and leading zeros are there just to try and get a rough grid layout)

Comment: This is basic stuff. [VLOOKUP function - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem?

Comment: Lee, I've just added a sample grid. I'm trying to do a find using formulae over the grid not just one row or column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm sure that you are looking for this one:**

[image]

*This Array Formula will find, Row position:*

```
{=SMALL(IF($A$7=$A$1:$D$5, ROW($A$1:$D$5)-ROW($A$1)+1), ROW(1:1))}
```

*And this finds Column position:*

```
{=SMALL(IF($A$7=$A$1:$D$5, ROW($A$1:$D$5)+COLUMN($A$1)+0), ROW(1:1))}
```

**Note:**

- Finish both Formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the introduction to array formulas, very helpful

Comment: @johnc,, glad to help you keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

> I would like a formula to search for the first occurrence of the value X and return its location within the A1:E10 range.

Assuming that the reason you want the "location" of the value X is because you're planning to nest it inside of a second formula to use that location to look up a value in another column... then what you actually want is **VLOOKUP**.  This will let you do it in one function instead of two.

Given a grid like this:

[image]

You would use the formula `=VLOOKUP("X", A1:E10, 5, FALSE)`.

Your first argument, "X", is the value in the first column that you want to reference.

Your second argument, A1:E10, is the range in which you are looking up a value.

Your third argument, 5, is the column number in that range (E is the 5th column in the A through E range).

Your fourth argument is whether or not to look for an exact match.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful response. Unfortunately my question was not as clear as should have been.  I'm trying to be search for a value eg 99 in any column A to E (row 1 to 10).

Comment: Hmmmm, so in this case, if you wanted X, you would actually want to return a _location_, as in A2?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the _location_?  Plug it into another formula?  Or just display it and not actually do anything else with it?

Comment: I guess this is what you actually want:
https://exceljet.net/formula/get-address-of-lookup-result

Comment: That only searches on one column. I'd like something that searches all columns for the key value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87466/discussion-between-johnc-and-james-dunn).